# How to show a div after scrolling to the top of another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, operator-keyword

I'm trying to make a sticky header visible when the top of a div is hit and then, invisible when the top of a second div below is hit

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code :

```
var iconsetTop = $('.icon-sets').offset().top;
var bundleTop = $('.bundle-offer').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ((iconsetTop >= $(window).scrollTop()) && (bundleTop >= $(window).scrollTop())){
        $('.set-header').css("top","-20%");
    } else {
        $('.set-header').css("top","0");
    }  
});
```

I think something is doesn't work with the use of the && operator, but I can't find out what. Also, I created en codepen to illustrate : http://codepen.io/jeremyobriot/pen/zqdpyJ

Thanks by advance for the help !

Comment: Looks like you are checking with a target that is moving. Don't rely on dynamic objects.

Comment: The [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOopWv) works as it should.

Comment: @PraveenKumar but it doesnt work as he wants it to work. He wants (form my understanding) to get the black fixed menu bar to disappear on the light pink background

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for your answer. 
My aim is to make the black div on the codepen (.set-header) disappear when it hits the pink div (.bundle-offer). It doesn't work this way on the codepen, the black div stay visible.

Comment: @Craicerjack That's right, thank you to make my question clearer :)

Comment: @jeremy_o, Doesn't the fix in my answer do that? or I am missing the point.

Comment: @Starx not exactly, because the header was visible without any scroll and I was tryin to make it appear only after he hit the dark pink and disappear after hitting the top of the light pink. Next time I will not using to pink divs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this? The header is only visible inside the red box.

I made a statement where I ask if `scrollTop` of the window is higher than the iconset top and lower than the bundle top.

```js
var iconsetTop = $('.icon-sets').offset().top;
var bundleTop = $('.bundle-offer').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= iconsetTop && $(window).scrollTop() <= bundleTop) {
    $('.set-header').css("top", "0");
  } else {
    $('.set-header').css("top", "-20%");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.set-header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -20%;
}

.space {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.icon-sets {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: IndianRed;
}

.bundle-offer {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="set-header"></div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="icon-sets"></div>
<div class="bundle-offer"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, so what are you trying to say here? :)

Comment: Asking if this is the way where he is looking for duh

Comment: I mean, don't I get that? I am asking what have you changed? And why?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not totally clear, @NiZa found the solution. Thank for your help !

Comment: @PraveenKumar He would like it invisible first, on blue div. Visible on dark pink/red div. then invisible again on light pink div. If you look at his codepen and then the accepted answer you will see the difference

Comment: Man! I didn't see the pink div at all. Wow.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar bad color choice, my bad !